# How to customize files pattern while using rgrep?

Tags: regular-expressions, elpy, rgrep

elpy-mode internally uses this command to search for a `regexp` in *.py files.

```
(setq elpy-rgrep-file-pattern "*.py")

(rgrep regexp
       elpy-rgrep-file-pattern
       default-directory))
```

However `elpy-rgrep-file-pattern` is customisable. I want to include html files also while searching.

I have tried the following patterns

```
(setq elpy-rgrep-file-pattern "*.py|*.html")
(setq elpy-rgrep-file-pattern "*.py\|*.html")
(setq elpy-rgrep-file-pattern "*.(py\|html)")
(setq elpy-rgrep-file-pattern "py\|html")
(setq elpy-rgrep-file-pattern '(("html" . "*.html") ("py" . "*.py")))
```

but nothing seems to work. How do I correctly specify file pattern to search *.py & *.html files?

Comment: If that's a regexp, you need two backslashes. First to escape the following backslash.

Comment: @wvxvw Not sure if that is a regexp, tried double back slash but it didn't work

Comment: OK, judging by the style of its definition, it must be a `glob` (similar to how Python or Bash `glob` works: https://github.com/jorgenschaefer/elpy/blob/7e81e3e995ac1c64a9a3d298d86b6858cce802d0/elpy.el#L298 . Oh, wait, `*.py` is a glob! but you cannot have union operator (pipe) in globs, it can only have `*` and `?`. And if you wanted to make it a regexp: `"\\.\\(:?py\\|html\\)$"`.

Comment: Even that is not working. May be we are missing something?

Comment: What I'm saying is that this variable uses globbing. This is not really a regular expression, it's just a pattern that can match strings using `?` as a placeholder for any character and `*` as a placeholder for multiple unknown characters. So you cannot really make it accept files with different extensions. I'm not sure why would anyone use this in Emacs Lisp though, rather than regular expression.

Comment: Oh, I think I figured that out, can you try this: `"*.py *.htm?"`? Also see documentation for `grep-files-aliases`.

Comment: That is grepping only `*.py` but ignoring `*.htm?`. I have checked `grep-files-aliases` and tried last pattern as mentioned in question.

Comment: What if you define an alias similar to other aliases in that variable and try to use that instead? If I do `(push (cons "pyml" "*.py *.htm *.html") grep-files-aliases)` and then `M-x rgerp` whatever `RET` pyml `RET`, then I get results for both `*.html` and `*.py` files.

Comment: Post it as answer please :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29201/discussion-between-chillaranand-and-wvxvw).

Comment: Regarding "I'm not sure why would anyone use this in Emacs Lisp though, rather than regular expression", that would be because it's *not* used in elisp -- those patterns are passed through to the `find` command (which can't be depended on to support regexp options; although if you were confident that it could, you could probably bind `find-name-arg` and use regexp patterns in place of the globs).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`rgrep` takes as its second argument file description in a format similar to [shell globbing](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/globbingref.html), which also exists in other languages, for example, [in Python](https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html).

There's also a useful variable in Emacs related to `rgrep`: `grep-files-aliases`, which can be customized to alias various file groups, for instance

```
(push (cons "pyml" "*.py *.htm *.html") grep-files-aliases)
```

will add an alias `pyml` for files with extensions `py`, `htm` and `html`.  After evaluating the code above, one should be able to execute:

<kbd>M-x</kbd>`rgrep`<kbd>RET</kbd>`search query`<kbd>RET</kbd>`pyml`<kbd>RET</kbd> in order to search in files with the extensions aliased by `pyml`.

Comment: Instead of constructing `pyml` and we can also pass `"*.py *.htm *.html"` directly as a pattern.

Answer (score 0):

`rgrep` does not accept spaces in the mini-buffer at the "files matching wildcard" prompt.

The workaround is to pass in:

```regex
*[.py,.htm,.html,pyml]
```

If just looking through extensions:

```regex
*.[py,htm,html]
```